# Calendar for an online store with delivery information. Only working days

Tags: javascript, calendar

Assumptions

1. If today is Friday and it is 10:00, the result should be:
   Order to Order until: 10:00 am, Friday 21/10/2022 with delivery Planned shipping date: Monday 24/10/2022 (The weekend extends the deadline to 1 business day)
2. If today is Friday and the time is 10:01, the result should be:
   Order to Order by: 10:00 am, Monday 24/10/2022 with delivery Planned shipping date: Tuesday 25/10/2022 ((The weekend extends the deadline to 1 business day)

- lastOrderDay - how many days to place the order
- lastOrderHour - Time to place the order (10:00)
- dayDelivery - how many days for realizations
- lastOrder - Final result with time to + date (To when order)
- nextDelivery - Final result with time to + date (When scheduled delivery)

```js
var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
var months = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
var lastOrderDay = 1;
var lastOrderHour = 10;
var dayDelivery = 2; 
var testHours = 12;

function findDates(dayOfWeek) {
  var date = new Date();
  if(date.getDay() >= lastOrderDay){
    if(date.getHours() > (lastOrderHour -1)){
      console.log('Next week');
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + (dayOfWeek + 7 - date.getDay()) % 14);
    }else{
      console.log('Keep this week');
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + (dayOfWeek + 7 - date.getDay()) % 7);
    }
  }else{
    console.log('This week');
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + (dayOfWeek - date.getDay()) % 7);
  }
  return date;
}
function displayDates(){
  var lastOrderDate = findDates(lastOrderDay);
  var deliveryDate = findDates(dayDelivery);
  var date = new Date();
  var txt_lastOrderDate ="Order does:" + lastOrderHour+":00, "+days[lastOrderDate.getDay()]+" "+("0" +lastOrderDate.getDate()).slice(-2)+"/"+months[lastOrderDate.getMonth()]  +"/"+ lastOrderDate.getFullYear();
  var txt_deliveryDate = "Scheduled Shipment: "+days[deliveryDate.getDay()]+" "+("0" +deliveryDate.getDate()).slice(-2)+"/"+months[deliveryDate.getMonth()] +"/"+ deliveryDate.getFullYear();
  if(date.getDay() == 3 && date.getHours() < lastOrderHour){
     txt_lastOrderDate = "Today, "+lastOrderHour+"am";
  }
  document.getElementById("lastOrder").innerHTML = txt_lastOrderDate;
  document.getElementById("nextDelivery").innerHTML = txt_deliveryDate;
}
displayDates();
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><span id="lastOrder"></span> <br><span id="nextDelivery"></span></div>
```

Could someone point out an error because the code does not work properly after 10:00 am does not add another day.